# Is the category of diffeological spaces a full subcategory of locally ringed spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, sheaf-theory, generalized-smooth-spaces, locally-ringed-spaces

It is known that the natural functor of smooth functions from the category of smooth manifolds into the category of locally ringed spaces is a full embedding (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225528/differentiable-manifolds-as-locally-ringed-spaces)).

1. Is a similar functor from the category of diffeological spaces to the category of locally ringed spaces a full embedding?
2. If so, what can be said about the abstract characterization of its image? An answer to a similar question for smooth manifolds can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88056/is-there-a-sheaf-theoretical-characterization-of-a-differentiable-manifold)

Comment: Almost certainly not. Diffelofical strucutre can capture very singular spaces, like the non-commutative torus, that have no smooth function defined on them. I really don't see a way to attach to them a locally ringed space in a way that capture any interesting information

Comment: @SimonHenry Thanks! In fact, I'm looking for a small extension of the category of smooth manifolds to include the important naturally occurring infinite-dimensional manifolds (such as spaces of smooth functions), but still being a full subcategory of locally ringed spaces. Apparently, diffiological spaces are not suitable for my purposes. Now I asked this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419014/cartesian-closed-full-subcategory-of-locally-ringed-spaces-containing-smooth-man) separately.

Comment: @SimonHenry: what do you mean by "have no smooth function defined on them"? Every diffeological space has smooth functions, for example all constant ones.

Comment: I mean't no non-constant smooth functions to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And did you mean the "irrational" torus instead of "non-commutative"? Because the D-topology of the irrational torus is discrete, so it seems to fit very well that it doesn't have non-constant smooth functions.

Comment: @SimonHenry: Ok, now I see your point. The irrational torus has only constant smooth functions and has the discrete D-topology. Hence, it can not be distinguished from the discrete torus as locally ringed spaces. However, it is not diffeomorphic to the discrete torus. This shows that the functor is not full. Correct?

Comment: Essentially yes. I wouldn't say it "shows" because the question didn't really specify how you build a locally ringed space out of a diffeological spaces - but at least it shows that Naive constructions using smooth function don't distinguish between the different non-commutative torus (or Irrational if you prefer). It is different from the discrete space though : the discrete space has plenty of non-constant smooth functions on it.

Comment: I am not aware of a "nice" embedding functor of diffeological spaces into locally ringed spaces. However, maybe you find the framework of $C^\infty$-rings and locally $C^\infty$-ringed spaces helpful; see, for instance, the book "Smooth infinitesimal analysis" by Moerdijk and Reyes, as well as Dominic Joyce's https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0023v7.

Comment: @SeverinBunk Thank you very much for the link to this book! I have long been interested in synthetic differential geometry - I think now that this is the best approach. But unfortunately it doesn't help me now -- [see this comment of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419014/cartesian-closed-full-subcategory-of-locally-ringed-spaces-containing-smooth-man#comment1076063_419014) (correct me if I'm wrong)