# Minimal regularity for domains in Green's formula

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration, regularity

The Green formula is well-known for **smooth** bounded domains of $\mathbb R^d$. My question is:

What is the **minimal** regularity known for domains where Green's formula still holds?

Comment: "Set of finite perimeter" is a kind of distributional notion of a set for which Green's formula is valid. There are sophisticated characterizations of these due to De Giorgi, Federer, etc. If you mean something other than this, it's probably a good idea to be specific with exactly what you are referring to as "Green's formula."

Comment: [This Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358606/on-which-regions-can-greens-theorem-not-be-applied) is really relevant, in such a way that it could be misunderstood as a duplicate. Less deep, but more detailed, also [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835353/domains-for-which-the-divergence-theorem-holds) could be of some help.